# Win 10 Update disables align to grid option

Tags: windows-10

Just bought a new Dell XPS with Windows 10. All updates installed. Align to grid feature on Desktop View no longer gives option to disable 'align to grid...despite being unchecked.' Icons are bounced around when they are dragged far left/right/strong textup or down.

Answer (score 1):

This can still be done from the registry.

1. Start > type `regedit`
2. Navigate to key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Desktop`
3. Change value of `FFlags` to `1075839521` (choose decimal before pasting number)

This value tells windows to auto-arrange icons, but to turn off align to grid.

After you make this change, you can restart your machine for it to take effect, or open task manager, right click on `Windows Explorer` under the `Processes` tab (usually at the bottom) and choose `restart`.

Comment: Is there an edit that will turn off auto-arrange as well? Or can that be stilldone via desktop/view?